# Deploy site made with React JS on GitHub pages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github-pages

Actually, I created my first React JS application using the `create-react-app` from cmd line.

**Before running `npm run build`**

Now the problem is that the GitHub page shows 404. when I move to username.github.io/project-name/public the console shows 400 error and a blank page

**After running `npm run build`**

```
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  39.92 KB  build\static\js\main.a7e4b607.js
  109 B     build\static\css\main.65027555.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /project-name/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
To publish it at http://username.github.io/project-name, run:

  npm install --save-dev gh-pages

Add the following script in your package.json.

    // ...
    "scripts": {
      // ...
      "predeploy": "npm run build",
      "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
    }

Then run:

  npm run deploy
```

After running the `npm run deploy` I get this error.

> error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1) fatal: could not
>   read Username for 'https://github.com': No error

How to fix this error? Can we host react js app on GitHub pages that don't require the database?

**Edit -**
My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://username.github.io/project-name",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.14"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

This is what I have in my package.json file.

Comment: You should be able to host the react site. But that may require react cdn links in your head element. I think you could just go to settings in the git repo and set the master branch to be the github pages branch.

Comment: That's what I did there is no option for gh-pages so I selected the master branch as the GitHub page.

Comment: Did you add the `homepage` property to your package.json as it states [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#github-pages)?

Comment: @bennygenel yes, I added and gave a rebuild. Still a 404 page.

Comment: React scripts ver 1.0.14

Comment: Might be because `"gh-pages"` is devDependency maybe?

Comment: Nope that did not work still same error

Comment: @RajendranNadar , your package.json looks alright. Based on your error message, I suspect it is due to your git configuration. Are you able to push to your GitHub repo manually?

Comment: @RajendranNadar, also, you mentioned "username.github.io/project-name/public" in your question. That doesn't look right. It should be just " username.github.io/project-name" containing the files from your build folder.

Comment: @RajendranNadar, "there is no option for gh-pages" because you need to first push the "gh-pages" to GitHub, only then the option will appear. See https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to just host the `create-react-app` on GitHub Pages, you don't actually need the `gh-pages` package.

### Manual way:

After you run `npm run build`, the build output is in the `build` folder. Make a copy of those files in the `build` folder.

Create a branch called `gh-pages` in your repo. Checkout the `gh-pages` branch. Delete everything and paste the copied files in this `gh-pages` branch. Commit and push to your GitHub repo.

Go to your GitHub repo settings and setup the GitHub Pages using `gh-pages` branch. (See https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/)

Visit `username.github.io/project-name` and you should be able to see your app.

### Automated way:

It is actually much easier if you use service like [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) or [Circle CI](https://circleci.com/).

For Travis CI example, take a look at this article: [6 simple steps to automatically test and deploy your JavaScript app to GitHub Pages](https://medium.com/@bezgachev/6-simple-steps-to-automatically-test-and-deploy-your-javascript-app-to-github-pages-c4c32a34bcb1)

When you have set this up, every time you push changes in `master` branch to GitHub repo, Travis CI will automatically build and deploy to your GitHub Pages.